# React - how to add N number of data properties to a reusable functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is this something that is possible? I keep getting some weird errors, again the dataAttribute should not be finite.

```
//
export default function Input({
  dataAttributes=null,
 
}) 

  return (
    <input class="" {...dataAttributes}/>
 
  );
}
```

```
import Input from "./Input"
<Input dataAttributes={'data-title':'this title', 'data-someting':'this is something else', ...add more}/>
```

to dom

```
<input data-title="this title" data-something="this is something else" ...whatever else was added/>
```

Comment: Have you tried with function Input(props) and then to pass the parameters <input {...props}> . Let me know if it works

Comment: @JorgePérez isn't that what im sort of doing? without using the word "props" could you give me a little more detailed example

Comment: try dataAttributes={{data_title:"this title", data_something:"this is something else}}

Comment: @Shynras it worked, just didn't click to me to add the extra {}

Comment: the first brackets are to use javascript inside the tags, the second are for the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double brackets inside the Input tag. The first pair is to write javascript inside tags, the second pair are for the object you're declaring.

```
<Input dataAttributes={{'data-title':'this title', 'data-someting':'this is something else', ...add more}}/>
```